# Writing own Split function for earlier version of VB. How to handle multiple delimiters in a row?

Tags: string, vb6, split

The following Split function found at support.microsoft.com does not create array values corresponding to consecutive delimiters.

eg. the string "hello|world||today" would generate the array: `arr[0] = "hello", arr[1] = "world", arr[2] = "today"` instead of the more correct: `arr[0] = "hello", arr[1] = "world", arr[2] = "", arr[3] = "today"`. How can I correct the code so that the latter result is generated?

```
     Public Function Split(ByVal sIn As String, Optional sDelim As _
            String, Optional nLimit As Long = -1, Optional bCompare As _
             VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare) As Variant
          Dim sRead As String, sOut() As String, nC As Integer
          If sDelim = "" Then
              Split = sIn
          End If
          sRead = ReadUntil(sIn, sDelim, bCompare)
          Do
              ReDim Preserve sOut(nC)
              sOut(nC) = sRead
              nC = nC + 1
              If nLimit <> -1 And nC >= nLimit Then Exit Do
              sRead = ReadUntil(sIn, sDelim)
          Loop While sRead <> ""
          ReDim Preserve sOut(nC)
          sOut(nC) = sIn
          Split = sOut
      End Function

      Public Function ReadUntil(ByRef sIn As String, _
            sDelim As String, Optional bCompare As VbCompareMethod _
          = vbBinaryCompare) As String
          Dim nPos As String
          nPos = InStr(1, sIn, sDelim, bCompare)
          If nPos > 0 Then
              ReadUntil = Left(sIn, nPos - 1)
              sIn = Mid(sIn, nPos + Len(sDelim))
          End If
      End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this with many combinations but it seems to do the trick.  I changed the condition on the loop, what value is entered as the last item in the array and added an else in ReadUntil.

```
Public Function Split(ByVal sIn As String, Optional sDelim As _
      String, Optional nLimit As Long = -1, Optional bCompare As _
       VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare) As Variant
    Dim sRead As String, sOut() As String, nC As Integer
    If sDelim = "" Then
        Split = sIn
    End If
    sRead = ReadUntil(sIn, sDelim, bCompare)
    Do
        ReDim Preserve sOut(nC)
        sOut(nC) = sRead
        nC = nC + 1
        If nLimit <> -1 And nC >= nLimit Then Exit Do
        sRead = ReadUntil(sIn, sDelim)
    Loop While sIn <> ""
    ReDim Preserve sOut(nC)
    sOut(nC) = sRead
    Split = sOut
End Function

Public Function ReadUntil(ByRef sIn As String, _
      sDelim As String, Optional bCompare As VbCompareMethod _
    = vbBinaryCompare) As String
    Dim nPos As String
    nPos = InStr(1, sIn, sDelim, bCompare)
    If nPos > 0 Then
        ReadUntil = Left(sIn, nPos - 1)
        sIn = Mid(sIn, nPos + Len(sDelim))
    Else
        ReadUntil = sIn
        sIn = ""
    End If
End Function
```